# How to align child text element to the bottom of input text elements

Tags: html, css, input, text, alignment

I created an HTML element for users to input floating-point values and I split up the input into two input elements, one for the whole number and the other for the decimal. I include a decimal point as a text element in between the two input text elements but it is not aligned to the bottom of both input elements and I am not sure how to fix this issue. Here is a snippet of my code:

```css
#whole {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#decimal {
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#decimal_point {
  vertical-align: bottom;  /*align decimal point to bottom*/
}
```

```html
<div>
       <input type=text maxlength=1 id=whole name=whole value=>
       <span id=decimal_point> . </span>
       <input type=text maxlength=3 id=decimal name=decimal value=>
    </div>
```

I updated the code and getting this issue:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use css `vertical-align` property on the `span` element.  Like so:

```css
.decimal-box span{
    vertical-align: bottom;  /*align decimal point to bottom*/
    line-height: 0.7; /* If desired, set line-height to push decimal point further down*/
}

#whole {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#decimal {
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="decimal-box">
     <input type="text" maxlength=1 id="whole" name="whole" value="">
     <span> . </span>
     <input type="text" maxlength="3" id="decimal" name="decimal" value="">
 </div>
```

Comment: So as I can see from running the snippet, it does move the decimal point down but it is not exactly inline with the bottoms of the two input elements.

Comment: @NoahTanenholtz, yes that's because of the `line-height` of the decimal point.  To adjust it all the way to the bottom, set the `line-height` of the `span` to like: `0.7` .  There.. I edited the snippet to adjust the decimal point even with the bottom. :)

Comment: I see that, so I tested out the code for my application. The issue that I am having is that because everything is centered inside the parent div, the decimal point (span) gets moved too far down. I posted a picture and updated the code to your solution so that you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: @NoahTanenholtz, yeah, to help I would need to see the css of the parent div.  Maybe can you make a codepen or jsfiddle example and send the link?

Comment: @NoahTanenholtz, Oh I see your edited question.  You can then adjust the `line-height` of the `span` to something like `1.2`..  That should do it.  Another option would be to also vertical-align the `input` elements.

Comment: @NoahTanenholtz, are you using a css library, like Bootstrap or something?  If so, let me know what you are using, and the version.

Comment: I am not using bootstrap, though I can since I know bootstrap is great for styling. I'm just not sure how to use it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you could set it into a div with and id instead of a span,

```
#whole {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#decimal {
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
#dpoint{
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;

}
.wrap{
  display: inline-flex;
}

  <div class="wrap">
    <input type=text maxlength=1 id=whole name=whole value=>
    <div id="dpoint"> . </div>
    <input type=text maxlength=3 id=decimal name=decimal value=>
 </div>
```

or you can add the style in the html within the div element and keep your css as is

```
  <div style="display: inline-flex;">
    <input type=text maxlength=1 id=whole name=whole value=>
    <div style='margin-top: 20px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;'> . </div>
    <input type=text maxlength=3 id=decimal name=decimal value=>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So after trial and error on vertical-align of the span element (decimal point) I found a better solution that seemed to work for my application. I have attached the snippet.

```css
decimal-box span{
    vertical-align: sub;  /* align decimal point to bottom */
}

#whole {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#decimal {
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="decimal-box">
     <input type="text" maxlength=1 id="whole" name="whole" value="">
     <span> . </span>
     <input type="text" maxlength="3" id="decimal" name="decimal" value="">
 </div>
```

You might not be able to tell the difference when running the snippet but here is a picture of it working for my application:

[image]